# preg_replace to include decimal point

Tags: preg-replace, str-replace

I have currency values within a table and for filtering I want to show only the numbers without currency symbols, but, I need the decimal point, here's what i'm using

```
$price_check = preg_replace('/\D/', '', str_replace(',','',(str_replace('&#163;','',$item[item_price])));
```

How do I keep the decimal point? is first question

Also, I'm removing `&#163;` first (ascii for GBP) and then removing comma (if present) - is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, the preg_replace anyway

```
$price_check = preg_replace('/(\.[0-9]+?)0*$/', '$1', str_replace(',','',(str_replace('&#163;','',$item[item_price]))));
```